# Uncaught type error nombreMascota is don´t a constructor " En archivo js , que recoge la información de un formulario

Tags: javascript

```js
let prop = document.getElementById('propietario').nodeValue;
let nombreMascota = document.getElementById('nombreMascota').nodeValue;
let direccion= document.getElementById('direccion').value;
let telefono = document.getElementById('telefono').value;
let enfermedad = document.getElementById('enfermedad').value;
let tipo = document.getElementById('tipo').value;

if(tipo=="perro") {
let perro = new nombreMascota(prop,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad);
    mostrarResult(perro);
}
else if(tipo=="gato"){
    let gato = new nombreMascota(prop,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad);
    mostrarResult(gato);
}
else if(tipo=="conejo") {
    let conejo = new nombreMascota(prop,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreMascota,enfermedad);
    mostrarResult(conejo); 
}

let mostrarResult = (valor)=> {
    let resultado = document.querySelector('#resultado ul')
    resultado.innerHTML=" ";
    
    let li1 = document.createElement('li');
    li1.innerHTML=`${valor.datosPropietario()}`;
    let li2 = document.createElement('li');
    li2.innerHTML = `${valor.tipo()}, mientras que el nombre de la mascota es : ${valor.nombreM()} y la enfermedad es :${valor.enfermedad()}`;
    resultado.appendChild(li1);
    resultado.appendChild(li2);
}

formulario.addEventListener('submit',mostrarResult);


class Propietario {
    constructor(nombreP,direccion,telefono){
        this.nombreP=nombreP;
        this.direccion=direccion;
        this.telefono=telefono;
    }
    datosPropietario(){
        return `El nombre del dueño es : ${this.nombreP} El domicilio es : ${this.direccion}, y el telefono de contacto : ${this.telefono}`;

    }
};

class Animal extends Propietario {
    constructor(nombreP,direccion,telefono,tipo){
        super(nombreP,direccion,telefono)
        this.tipo=tipo;
    }
    get tipo(){
        return `El tipo de animal es un : ${this._tipo}`;
    }
    };

class Mascota extends Animal {
    constructor(nombreP,direccion,telefono,tipo,nombreM,enfermedad){
        super(nombreP,direccion,telefono,tipo);
        this._nombreM=nombreM;
        this._enfermedad=enfermedad;
    }
    get nombreM(){
        return this._nombreM    }
    get enfermedad() {
        return this._enfermedad    }

    set nombreM(nombreM_nuevo){
        this.nombreM=nombreM_nuevo;    }

    set enfermedad(enfermedad_nuevo){
        this._enfermedad=enfermedad_nuevo;    }
        
}
```

```css
form {
    font-family: 'Tajawal', sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Tajawal:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet"> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./assets/css/style.css">
    <title>Desafio</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="mx-auto text-center">
            <img src="./assets/img/conejo-perro-gato.jpg" alt="animales" class="img-fluid">
            <h2 class="my-3">Consulta Veterinaria</h2>
        </div>
        <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="propietario">Dueño: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="propietario" aria-describedby="textoAyuda">
              <small id="textoAyuda" class="form-text text-muted">Nunca compartiremos tus datos.</small>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="telefono">Numero Telefonico: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="telefono">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="direccion">Lugar de Residencia: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="direccion">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="nombreMascota">Nombre de la Mascota: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="nombreMascota">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="tipo">Tipo</label>
                <select class="form-control" id="tipo">
                  <option value="perro">Perro</option>
                  <option value="gato">Gato</option>
                  <option value="conejo">Conejo</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="enfermedad">Motivo de la consulta: </label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="enfermedad">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Agregar</button>
          </form>
          <div class="text-center mt-5">
              <p>Datos Agregados</p>
              <div id="resultado">
                  <ul></ul>
              </div>
          </div>
    </div>
    <script src="./assets/js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Este código está diseñado para recoger información desde un formulario e insertarlo en la sección datos agregados . Al intentar ejecutarlo , esta ejecución no se realiza, esto es , no produce ningún registro de información , que haya sido vertida en el formulario. Cuando reviso la consola , aparece un error " Uncaught type error nombreMascota is don´t a constructor " , esto es en la línea 9 del archivo js. Me imagino , que también se hará extensible a las siguientes líneas de código que utilizan esta expresión. Ante esto mi duda es saber de qué manera hay que arreglar esto para de esa manera permitir que el código funcione.

Comment: `nombreMascota` no está definido, quizá sea `Mascota` que si está definido como una clase.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta. Lo que pasa es que si modifico nombreMascota por Mascota , la consola lanza el error unacught Reference Error :Cannot access 'Mascota' before initialization , por lo que obviamente el script no se ejecuta .

Comment: Casi 3 años tarde: El error que mencionaste se debe a que la clase Mascota no fue creada al momento de intentar instanciarla. La solución es primero crear la clase Mascota (por lo menos, antes de if(tipo=="perro")) y luego la instancias.